# Ruby on Rails - rake install/unpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the main difference between:

```
rake gems:install
rake gems:unpack
```

I had a problem with it telling me I was missing these gems. I did the rake gems:install. Then I thought I had installed the gems. But it said again , I was missing gems. After I did rake gems:unpack. It fixed the problem. Why is that?

```
####com@#.com [~/rails_apps/employee_tracker]# rake db:migrate
```

(in /home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker)
Missing these required gems:
  authlogic
  acl9

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home2/#com/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

## com@#.com [~/rails_apps/employee_tracker]# rake gems:install

(in /home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker)
gem install authlogic
Successfully installed authlogic-2.1.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for authlogic-2.1.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for authlogic-2.1.6...
gem install acl9 --source http://gemcutter.org
Successfully installed acl9-0.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for acl9-0.12.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for acl9-0.12.0...

## com@#.com [~/rails_apps/employee_tracker]# rake db:migrate

(in /home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker)
Missing these required gems:
  authlogic
  acl9

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home2/#com/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

## com@#.com [~/rails_apps/employee_tracker]# rake gems:unpack

(in /home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker)
gem install authlogic
Successfully installed authlogic-2.1.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for authlogic-2.1.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for authlogic-2.1.6...
gem install acl9 --source http://gemcutter.org
Successfully installed acl9-0.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for acl9-0.12.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for acl9-0.12.0...
Unpacked gem: '/home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker/vendor/gems/authlogic-2.1.6'
Unpacked gem: '/home2/#com/rails_apps/employee_tracker/vendor/gems/acl9-0.12.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rake gems:install does what you would expect. It calls out to rubygems.org and downloads the gems specified in the Gemfile/environment.rb.

rake gems:unpack unzips the contents of the gems specified in the Gemfile/environment.rb into your vendor/gems folder.

I believe you are just not specifying your gems and just trying to use them without adding them to the project via Gemfile(Rails 3)/environment.rb(Rails 2.X). Anything in vendor/gems is loaded automatically which I think would explain what you are seeing.

You should be putting

```
config.gem 'name_of_gem'
```

in your environment.rb file for the gems to be added.
Rails3 has a file called Gemfile where you do:

```
gem 'name_of_gem'
```

I hope that helps.